# Remainder of Second order Taylor expansion of a $C^2$ function is uniformly little oh in a compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, taylor-expansion

I am reading the proof of Ito's Lemma from the following post : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/20/itos-lemma/

We are assuming that $X=(X^1, \dots, X^d)$ is a continuous process taking values in an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. And $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously differentiable function. In this case, clearly the image of $f(X)$ over any bounded interval $[0,T]$ is a compact subset of $U$. But why does that give that the remainder term $R_{st}$ of the second order Taylor exapnsion be of order $o(\Vert X_t - X_s\Vert^2)$ uniformly over the interval $[0,T]$?

If $f$ was $C^3$, I  can see this from the Taylor Remainder formula as in the Mean Value Formulas : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem since $f^{(3)}$ has compact support, but I cannot find a Remainder formula in the $C^2$ case that gives the remainder of the second order expansion to be uniformly little oh of the difference.

[image]